# What is the password they are requesting to generate key hashes for development environments?

Tags: android-studio, passwords, android-keystore, keystore-access

I am using android facebook sdk to have a facebook login functionality in my app. I am following this guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ to do so. It was stated to run the command " keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl
base64 " in the Java SDK folder to generate a key. After I did it, I was prompted to enter a password but it is not clear as to what password they ask of me. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default password for debug keystore is `android`. You can check here:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Please note that you need not only a SHA-1 fingerprint of a debug key you mentioned but also a SHA-1 fingerprint of a **release key** to open your app to the public. 
You can make and handle release key in multiple way. Check here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing